# Getting an edit token for a mediaWiki fauxRequest

Tags: php, mediawiki, token

I am using mediaWiki's fauxRequest to do internal API calls. But I need an edit token to do it. I thought this would work, and it does report back a token, nit the request says it is a 'badtoken: Invalid token'

```
global $wgRequest;
$token = $wgRequest->getSessionData( 'wsEditToken' );
```

Any ideas?

I just noticed when I logout, the token it gives me is the same token as when I log in. Seems like this method is not looking at my session when it attempts to get the token.

---

**I am not allowed to answer my own question yet, so here it is.**

I was lead astray by bad examples. The answer was very easy.

```
global $wgUser;
$wgUser->editToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was lead astray by bad examples. The answer was very easy.

global $wgUser;
$wgUser->editToken();